# jQuery validate while using .submit() or .load()

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that is loading the results into a div, and jquery validate doesn't recognize that I need my field validated because there is no actual "Submit" going on, right? How can I bypass this and still validate my field?

```
$('#IDsearchform').validate({
    rules: {
        term: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
    }
});
```

..no worky :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IDsearchform').validate({
        rules: {
            term: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
        }
    }); 
    $('.activeView').click(function() {
        $('.activeMask').slideToggle(250);
        $('.list-style-arrow').toggleClass('nudge');
    });
        function showLoader(){
            $('.search-background').fadeIn(200);
        }
        //hide loading bar
        function hideLoader(){
            $('.sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
            $('.search-background').fadeOut(200);
        };
        $('.searchInput').keydown(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#IDsearchform').valid();
            showLoader();
            $('.sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
            $('.content .sub_cont').load('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), hideLoader());
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          });     
        $('.searchBtn').click(function(){
            $('#IDsearchform').valid();
            //show the loading bar
            showLoader();
            $('.sub_cont .loader').fadeIn(1500);         
            $('.content .sub_cont').load('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), hideLoader());

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call when you want to validate it

```
$('#IDsearchform').valid();
```

that will return true or false

EDIT with new information

```
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            if($('#IDsearchform').valid()){
             showLoader();
            $('.sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
            $('.content .sub_cont').load('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), hideLoader());

             }
            e.preventDefault();
          }
```

Comment: Ok so where do I place this, where my .load() is? or up near the validate();

Comment: Place it where ever you want to validate the form outside of submit. When do you want to validate your form?

Comment: I have a click and keydown functions associated with submitting the form, I tried placing this inside those

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve. If you have a form with rules like your original question. You can validate it anytime after the rule has been created. Make sure your validation rules execute, then on a click or keydown execute the valid() function. It would be helpful if you give more information in your original question, try to post the HTML and where exactly you initial jvalidate, and when you want to validate

Comment: OK I added my extra code - see I have my keydown and click functions with valid(); inside them, but it still loads my results with 1 or 2 characters in the field. ??

Comment: you'll need to return false if it doesnt validate. ill edit my answer